# Importing other function in Stimulus controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

In a Stimulus controller in Rails 7 I am importing functions from another js file in my /javascript directory

```
import * as myHelpers from "../helpers/my_helpers.js";
```

This works fine in development, but in production I get a 404 for the included file as it is being looked for at `/assets/helpers/my_helpers.js` . Do the javascript controllers move in production?  Is there a way to reference this file?

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by using the import map config/importmap.rb:

```
pin_all_from "app/javascript/helpers", under: "helpers"
```

And then in the controller

```
import * as myHelpers from "helpers/my_helpers";
```

Comment: What's inside the my_helpers.js file? How do you state helper functions?